# Do the Visual Studio 2013 Previews Expire

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio

I have `Visual Studio 2012 Professional` and would like to try out the `Visual Studio 2013 Previews`. Will the previews expire (stop working) when Microsoft releases the commercial version?

Comment: You can download the preview on Windows 8, even Windows 7 http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/2013-editions#d-professional

Comment: @inixsoftware - Yes the preview license is time limited.  When they expire I am not 100% sure.  Your likely looking at a time window around the same length as the `Windows 8.1 Preview`